# unable to get collvoid plugin planner for navigation stack to move the robot?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have been trying to get the multi robot collision avoidance package working with the navigation stack. I set up the launch files similar to the examples provided in the package and can display the costmaps, global and local plans made by the collvoid planner. When I send move_base a goal using rviz or a simple package I get a warning

```
[ WARN] [1348232889.899224274]: MSG to TF: Quaternion Not Properly Normalized.
```

I have checked the goals sent to it and they are normalized. The collvoid package doesn't correctly move the robot to the goal even though it's planned a global and local path to it. The robot just rotates from side to side and moves forward very slowly. When I use a different planner like navfn then I don't get this warning and the robot moves correctly along paths. Has anyone got this package working well with fuerte and the navigation stack?

[image: image description]

The blue line is the global plan and the purple line is the local plan. The goal was selected from publishing a selected goal from rviz on the move_base_simple/goal which already normalizes the quaternion for you.

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <param name="oscillation_timeout" value="30.0" />
    <param name="oscillation_distance" value="0.5" />
    <param name="base_global_planner" value="collvoid_simple_global_planner/CollvoidSimpleGlobalPlanner" />  
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="collvoid_local_planner/CollvoidLocalPlanner" />
    <rosparam file="$(find wambot5_2dnav)/CollvoidLocalPlanner_params.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

CollvoidLocalPlanner_params.yaml

---

```
controller_frequency: 10

CollvoidLocalPlanner:
  max_neighbors: 10
  neighbor_dist: 1.0
  time_horizon: 5.0
  time_horizon_obst: 5.0
  threshold_last_seen: 1.0

  scale_radius_factor: 2.0

  yaw_goal_tolerance: 3.0
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.3
  latch_xy_goal_tolerance: false
  global_frame: /map
  wheel_base: 0.35
  time_to_holo: 0.4
  min_error_holo: 0.05
  max_error_holo: 0.10
  holo_robot: false
  delete_observations: false

  max_vel_x: 0.8
  max_vel_th: 0.1
  min_vel_x: 0.01
  min_vel_th: 0.1
  min_vel_theta_inplace: 0.05
  min_vel_y: 0.01
  max_vel_y: 0.1
  max_vel_with_obstacles: 0.2
  acc_lim_x: 1.0
  acc_lim_y: 0.0
  acc_lim_th: 0.5
  footprint_radius: 0.3
  inscribed_radius: 0.2

TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 0.50
  min_vel_x: 0.05
  max_rotational_vel: 1.0
  min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.01
  acc_lim_th: 0.75
  acc_lim_x: 0.50
  acc_lim_y: 0.50
  holonomic_robot: false
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 3.0
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.3
  goal_distance_bias: 0.8
  path_distance_bias: 1.0
  sim_time: 0.5
  heading_lookahead: 0.325
  oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05
  vx_samples: 6
  vtheta_samples: 20
  dwa: true
 
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 3.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 6.0
  height: 6.0
  resolution: 0.05

  #For this example we'll configure the costmap in voxel-grid mode
  map_type: voxel

  #Voxel grid specific parameters
  origin_z: 0.0
  z_resolution: 0.2
  z_voxels: 10
  unknown_threshold: 9
  mark_threshold: 0

  #Set the tolerance we're willing to have for tf transforms
  transform_tolerance: 0.8

  #Obstacle marking parameters
  obstacle_range: 2.5
  max_obstacle_height: 2.0
  raytrace_range: 3.0

  robot_radius: 0.35
  footprint: [[-0.279, -0.225], [-0.279, 0.225], [0.279, 0.225], [0.279, -0.225]]
  inflation_radius: 0.40
  footprint_padding: 0.01

  #Cost function parameters
  cost_scaling_factor: 10.0

  #The cost at which a cell is considered an obstacle when a map is read from the map_server
  lethal_cost_threshold: 100

  #Configuration for the sensors that the costmap will use to update a map
  observation_sources: scan
  scan: {data_type: LaserScan, expected_update_rate: 0.8,
  observation_persistence: 0.0, marking: true, clearing: true, max_obstacle_height: 0.4, min_obstacle_height: 0.02}

global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 3.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: true
  
  #For this example we'll configure the costmap in voxel-grid mode
  map_type: voxel

  #Voxel grid specific parameters
  origin_z: 0.0
  z_resolution: 0.2
  z_voxels: 10
  unknown_threshold: 9
  mark_threshold: 0

  #Set the tolerance we're willing to have for tf transforms
  transform_tolerance: 0.8

  #Obstacle marking parameters
  obstacle_range: 2.5
  max_obstacle_height: 2.0
  raytrace_range: 3.0

  robot_radius: 0.35
  footprint: [[-0.279, -0.225], [-0.279, 0.225], [0.279, 0.225], [0.279, -0.225]]
  inflation_radius: 0.40
  footprint_padding: 0.01

  #Cost function parameters
  cost_scaling_factor: 10.0

  #The cost at which a cell is considered an obstacle when a map is read from the map_server
  lethal_cost_threshold: 100
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44341/unable-to-get-collvoid-plugin-planner-for-navigation-stack-to-move-the-robot?/) by [Roy89](https://answers.ros.org/users/2154/roy89/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2012-09-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bbbExtremly](https://answers.ros.org/users/5281/bbbextremly/) on 2014-01-12**:
Would you mind sharing the source code of collvoid package? Because the original address is fail(rosws merge https://kforge.ros.org/collvoid/collvoid/raw-file/tip/collvoid.rosinstall) and I cannot download it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not supported for fuerte yet.

---

Originally posted by [Roy89](https://answers.ros.org/users/2154/roy89/) with karma: 133 on 2012-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0